# Como colocar mais de um parâmetro em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Pessoal eu estou aprendendo Python3 e estou com problemas pra fazer uma implementação em Python.

Por exemplo, em C:

```
for (fatorial = numero; fatorial >= 1; fatorial--)
```

Eu quero colocar essa implementação acima em python:
Já fiz assim:

```
for (fatorial = numero && fatorial >=1 && fatorial-1)
```

Já fiz assim:

```
for (fatorial = numero and fatorial >=1 and fatorial-1)
```

e assim:

```
for (fatorial = numero; fatorial >=1; fatorial-1)
```

E não deu certo. Como eu faço?

Meu código que eu consegui fazer funcionar:

```
 n = int (input("Digite um numero: "))

resultado = 1

lista = range(1,n+1)

for x in lista:

    resultado = x * resultado

print ("! =", n, resultado)
```

Vou colocar meu exemplo que eu fiz no Portugol Studio:

```
programa
{
inteiro numero, fatorial, resultado = 1
cadeia texto = "" //Variavel para salvar a representação final (3x2x1)

    funcao inicio()
    {

escreva ("Insira um número a ser fatorado: ")
leia (numero)


para (fatorial = numero; fatorial >= 1; fatorial--)
{
    // Aqui, se for 1 não precisamos concatenar o sinal de multiplicação (x)
    se(fatorial == 1){
        texto = texto + fatorial
    }senao{
        texto = texto + fatorial + "x"
    }

    resultado = resultado * fatorial
}

escreva (numero, "! = ", texto, " = ", resultado)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em python e for e um pouco diferente das outras linguagens, sendo:

```
for variavel_qualquer in range(valor_inicial,valor_de_Parada,incremento):
    print("Algo")
```

Com essa estrutura você pode fazer um numero finito de repetições, emulando o que você gostaria de fazer ficaria:

```
for x in range(fatorial,0,-1):
    print("Algo")
```

O 0 esta ai pois o for no python não executa  o loop quando atinge o numero de parada, então para poder manter o loop em quanto e maio ou igual a 1 e colocado para ser maio que 0.

Edit1: Convertendo seu pseudo-código para python e usando a ideia de concatenação e com a formatação com espaços como você queria.  seria algo perto disso:

```
n = int (input("Digite um numero: "))

resultado = 1
texto = ""

lista = range(1,n+1)

for x in lista:
    resultado = x * resultado
    if (x != 1):
        texto = str(x) + " x " + texto
    else:
        texto = str(x) + texto

print (texto + " =", resultado)
```

Comment: Então, Arcashaid. Eu consigo dessa forma aí. Mas eu queria colocar a implementação de modo que ele retornasse assim: <pre> 5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 = 120
</pre> Meu código tá assim: <pre>n = int (input("Digite um numero: "))

resultado = 1

lista = range(1,n+1)

for x in lista:

 resultado = x * resultado

print ("! =", n, resultado)</pre>

Comment: Por favor, edite sua pergunta e coloque o que você fez, assim fica mais fácil de visualizar e te ajudar.

Comment: Editei Arcashaid. Veja se vc consegue entender minha dúvida agora. Obrigado.

Comment: Espero que seja isso, caso ainda falte algo avise que eu modifico

Comment: Perfeito, Arcashaid! poderia me explicar o que significa isso?  str(x)

Comment: Em python você não pode concatenar um inteiro  com uma string, então eu usei o str para converter o inteiro  para uma string dele antes de concatenar, ou seja no lugar dos inteiros 5,4,3,2,1 do exemplo foi concatenados strings deles "5","4","3","2","1"  Ficou claro ?

Comment: Ah sim! Entendi. Eu fiz alguns exercícios que eu utilizei esse formato só não sabia o que significava. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 2):

O Python não tem o `for`tradicional livre do C. Precisa gerar uma faixa de dados de acordo com sua necessidade:

```
n = 1
numero = 5
for fatorial in range(numero, 1, -1):
    n = n * fatorial
print(n)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/EzEcQV). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/bzfmsnzq-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Syntax/ForDecreasing.py).

Comment: Então bigown. Eu consigo dessa forma aí. Mas eu queria colocar a implementação de modo que ele retornasse assim: <pre> 5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 = 120.

Comment: Aí não tem nada a ver com a pergunta, isso é detalhe do que colocar dentro do `for`.